# Calculated Weighted Standard Deviation from Standard Deviation and Weight Only

Tags: statistics

I have a table of unweighted means and standard deviations for some subsetted data, along with how many points of data contribute to each mean (the weight). All the data points are from the same data set, but are split by some categorical variables. Now I'm attempted to summarize all of the subsets of data with a weighted mean and SD. Because the subsets in my table may not be ALL of the possible subsets (by design), I can't just say "Get the standard deviation of the whole data set" and call it a day.

Long story short, I need to be able to calculate the weighted standard deviation using only the unweighted means, unweighted standard deviations, and weights of the subsets. I can derive intermediate steps from those things, and I can obtain additional information per subset if required, but can't access the original data as a whole except to do the latter.